# Flowers on a Piano

Tags: piano, maintenance

We just moved a baby grand into our new house.  It's the Kawai I grew up with as a child. Very excited!

My wife was excited too.  It looked like a great surface to provide a little decoration on.  She prepared a vase of flowers for it.  I, needless to say, was not comfortable in the least with this plan, but I'd like her to be able to do something with it.

Does anyone have experience with flowers on pianos?  Do I need to stick with nice lightweight fake flowers, or are there ways to make sure the accidental spill does not ruin my finish (polyester)?  Perhaps plants that are comfortable with their moisture being stored in a damp sponge so it can't spill?  A happy wife makes a happy life, but there are some cases where care is needed when applying that aphorism!

Comment: I thought it would be interesting to find some examples: http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=grand+piano+in+room -- that brought me to http://capid.org/2013/07/23/placing-a-grand-piano/ , which offers some good wisdom, for example "Some people like having accessories on the piano. But it implies the instrument is not frequently used. A grand piano looks the best with its lid open."

Comment: I would not want a vessel of water anywhere near my piano.

Comment: Also the vase may sweat leaving coaster rings that may ruin the lid.

Comment: search on "wet floral foam" -- this at least alleviates the spilling problem.

Comment: I would personally not want to take a chance.  As a real estate agent, I can't tell you how many wood floors I have seen damaged under places where plants were placed.  Not sure if the water leaks out of the bottom of the pot or perhaps splashes during watering.  The pot itself can trap water under it an not allow it to be seen or to evaporate.  Silk plant gets my vote as a compromise.

Comment: There might be 1000 other places in your home to put flowers. Please don't have a piano be one of them.

Comment: Simple solution: always play the piano with the lid up. Find somewhere "sensible" to move the flowers to (i.e. not on the floor underneath the piano!) and when you are done, leave them there. But don't leave the lid permanently up, otherwise worse things may end up inside a piano than the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm confused. The intention is that you'll never play the piano with the lid up at all? If so then why have it? We owned a baby grand when I was growing up and it got played every day, which meant the lid was always at half stick at least. There was no way to put anything on it except sheet music.

Comment: The biggest risk is liquids. I used to put my glass of beer on the piano while I played, but nowadays I "play it safe" and put the beer elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A piano generally has a really nice finish. It is a piece of (functional) furniture, not a shelf. At most, a plastic vase with plastic flowers (no liquid) placed on a fancy doily. Regular opening of the lid may dissuade others from putting things on the piano.

Answer (score 2):

She means well.  Perhaps you could focus her good intentions towards a nice arrangement of dried flowers.